# The named parameter 'isSetState' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter, provider

I am trying to use this parameter in Provider, but I ran into an error. What should I do to resolve it?

[image]

When I add the require parameter, it will be like an undre image

[image]

Comment: Please write code instead of screenshot next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is required means it can't be null in this case `isSetState` is set to `null` but it can only be either `true` or `false`.

If you pass `true` to `isSetState` attribute then the ui will update and if you pass `false` to `isSetState` attribute then the ui will not update.

Answer (score 1):

bool has only 2 values, true or false. so for the parameter `isSetState` type `true` if you want to rebuild, or `false` if you don't want to.
As isSetState is a required parameter, you have to pass a value needless

Upvote if it helps